# How to make half circular slider in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter. I am developing a music app. I want to half(180°) or more then half(180°-240°) circular slider which increase or decrease the volume.

[image: IMAGE IS HERE FOR REFERENCE]

Note:

Comment: Okay, looks great. What is the specific problem you need help with?

Comment: @nvoigt I want to make slider just like above image for my app. And also increase or decrease volume by moving the slider. I have no idea how to make like this.

Comment: Then you will need to read a good book or tutorial on the topic. This site is for asking *specific* questions to *specific* problems. If you cannot specify your problem yet because you don't know how to do it at all, you will need to start with a broader approach. Like a book or tutorial.

Comment: I have no idea as to how to do this, but you'll have to custom paint it or find a package that already provides such a slider.

Comment: @nvoigt I have implemented the slider which is horizontal and also increase-decrease volume perfectly, but i want to make that slider like above image. Can i use same slider which i use currently in my project or i have to implement different slider.

Comment: The first hit in Google when I just paste your question title into Google is a blog with a step by step approach to building such a slider. complete with diagrams and explanations.

Comment: Thanks for the question, Sumit. You're on the right track, but as @nvoigt has pointed out, you will need to edit your question to frame it around the specific goal you're trying to achieve. Include examples about what you have tried and why you're stuck.

Have a look at this handy little guide on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sleek_circular_slider` from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/sleek_circular_slider)

Add the dependency to `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
    sleek_circular_slider : ^1.1.0
```

Run `flutter packages get` to fetch the dependencies.

Import it to your project file

```
import 'package:sleek_circular_slider/sleek_circular_slider.dart';
```

Then you can create the slider like so -

```
        final SleekCircularSlider(
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            initialValue: 0,
            onChange: (double value) {
              // callback providing a value while its being changed (with a pan gesture)
            },
            onChangeStart: (double startValue) {
              // callback providing a starting value (when a pan gesture starts)
            },
            onChangeEnd: (double endValue) {
              // callback providing an ending value (when a pan gesture ends)
            },
            innerWidget: (double value) {
              //This the widget that will show current value
              return Center(child: Text("${value.toInt().toString()} %", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),));
            },
          ),
```

This will create something like this -

[image]

You can read about more customization options [here](https://github.com/matthewfx/sleek_circular_slider).

Comment: Thanks, Its solve my problem 50%-60%. Do you know how to increase-decrease slider on button click.

Comment: Yeah, It should be pretty easy. Can you explain me this more in detail?

Comment: I have 2 buttons, 1st for decrease the vol and 2nd for increase the vol. When i click on 1st button vol should be decreased upto 0 & also slider get decrease and 2nd button vol  should be increased upto 20  & also slider get increase.  I have set the range min vol: 0 & max vol: 20.